# Microphone stops providing data with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm using `WaveInEvent` of `NAudio` to record microphone data. It works fine for a while, but after a few times, it stops providing input data- the `DataAvailable` callback is never called with new data.

I have tried creating a new `WaveInEvent` each time, but this did not resolve the problem. I've also tried using the WASAPI input, which always called `DataAvailable` - with zero bytes of data.

How can I record audio from the microphone reliably with `NAudio`?

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
StartRecording() {
    microphone = new WaveInEvent();
    microphone.DeviceNumber = 0;
    microphone.WaveFormat = outformat;
    microphone.BufferMilliseconds = 50;
    microphone.DataAvailable += (_, recArgs) =>
    {
        session.OnAudioData(recArgs.Buffer, recArgs.BytesRecorded);
    };
    microphone.StartRecording();
}
StopRecording() {
    if (microphone != null)
    {
        microphone.StopRecording();
        microphone.Dispose();
        microphone = null;
    }        
}
```

There's no other naudio code in the project except using WaveFormat to describe wave formats.

NAudio throws an access violation exception trying to call WaveInBuffer.Reuse() from a threadpool worker. I'm not sure why this doesn't do something more serious than just drop audio data.

For the condition where I did not recreate the WaveInEvent, I get an MmException instead- invalid handle calling waveInPrepareHeader, in the same place.

Frankly, the fact that I get different results heavily implies that NAudio is doing some funky shit it shouldn't to share state between instances, and looking at the source on Codeplex, I'm not really sure WTF is going on.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Are you getting an exception in the RecordingStopped event? Also, is this a USB capture device? If it is Realtek onboard sound, have you updated drivers?

Comment: @MarkHeath: I do get the exception in RecordingStopped and it is a USB capture device.

Comment: I've seen access violations NAudio before when something supposed to be pinned isn't and the GC moves it. But I thought we'd flushed out all such issues a long time ago. Can also be dodgy driver issues, and of course USB devices can become disconnected while in use. Does the stack trace of the exception point to which waveIn API call was generating the access violation?

Comment: @MarkHeath: It's StartRecording's lambda -> RecordThread() -> DoRecording() -> WaveInBuffer.Reuse(). If you don't want the GC to move a memory buffer, maybe it would be easier to simply use a native allocator like heapalloc/heapfree to allocate it? The USB device did not become disconnected. It is a standalone microphone with a record button, and it's in response to that button press that the above functions are being called.

Comment: @Puppy WaveInBuffer.Reuse calls three unmanaged Windows APIs - I was hoping the stack trace might indicate which one is causing the issue. The pinning code I use in WaveInBuffer/WaveOutBuffer has proven reliable for many years now, so I'd hope that isn't the cause in this instance.

Comment: The exception states that it's an invalid handle calling waveInPrepareHeader, so I'd go with that one. WaveInBuffer LGTM so I think that it must lie in an incorrect call to Dispose().

Comment: One possible issue with your code is that you call Dispose straight after calling StopRecording. Try holding off calling Dispose until you get the RecordingStopped event, which will be after any final buffers are processed.

Comment: @MarkHeath: That would imply that the correct disposal (or not) of one WaveInEvent affects the correctness of a completely separate instance of WaveInEvent. Also, I still get the problem in a slightly different form if I don't dispose and recreate.

Comment: I read through the whole source of both WaveInEvent and WaveInBuffer and both seem correct to me. I even checked for exception safety fails like not closing the device correctly. I can't find anything that would explain this behaviour. Perhaps it's an issue with the device driver?

Comment: I've been experimenting with WaveIn instead of WaveInEvent, but I keep getting "WaveStillPlaying calling waveUnprepareHeader". The internets suggested that this bug was also fixed a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the drivers for the USB microphone do not behave correctly. When the buffer is sent to the user through the WIM_DATA message, it is full. However when waveInUnprepareHeader is called, it's still in the queue, even though it was literally just passed as full. So I think that the drivers for the microphone are ultimately to blame.

I've been looking more closely at the microphone and it seems that this particular unit is actually known to have been damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you and i use WaveOut event in combination with WaveInEvent to solve the problem. For a mysterious reason, when used with WaveOut, WaveIn keeps recording infinitely:

```
var waveIn = new WaveInEvent();
    waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
    waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
    var sampleProvider = new WaveInProvider(waveIn);
    var volumeProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(sampleProvider.ToSampleProvider());
    volumeProvider.Volume = 0f; //Set the volume to 0 to turn off the sound
    var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
    waveOut.Init(volumeProvider);
    waveIn.DataAvailable += (sender, e) =>
    {
         .......
    }
    waveIn.StartRecording();
    waveOut.Play();
```